# Questarter.com copied all the content from Stack Exchange Network. Is it legal?

Tags: discussion

Today I found a site called https://www.questarter.com/.

If you checked it has almost all content from the Stack Exchange network. I think they are getting them from RSS feeds.

Can we get an action about that type of site or according to Terms of conditions of Stack Exchange it is a legal site?